# Google Closure Compiler warns of "expressions are not callable"

Tags: google-closure-compiler

In the following code, I get the warning:

> expressions are not callable

I am using the Google Closure Compiler. The warning occurs when the request object is called as a function. How can I get rid of this warning?

```
var request = require('request'); // See https://github.com/request/request

request({
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
    method: "POST",
    json: false,
    body: tokenPostData,
    headers: {
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
}, function (error, response, body) {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the solution. Just add "call" after the request object and make sure the first parameter value is "this".

```
var request = require('request'); // See https://github.com/request/request

request.call(this, {
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
    method: "POST",
    json: false,
    body: tokenPostData,
    headers: {
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
}, function (error, response, body) {

});
```